# Kendo Window - Don't Close Window on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I want to show a Kendo window and leave it up after the user clicks the submit image. I have googled for various terms in an attempt to find out how to do this, but have had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

jQuery:

```
function OpenPopupbusschallengeFromDrp(ddl) {
    $("#btnlnkButton").removeAttr("href");
    if (ddl.value != 0) {
        $("#btnlnkButton").attr("href", 
            "SubmitIdea.aspx?businessidea=" + ddl.value);
        $("#dvbusinesschallengedialouge").kendoWindow({
            width: "600px",
            height: "315px",
            title: "OPS Forum / Idea Exchange Challenge",
            visible: false, 
            actions: ["Close"], 
            close: ClosePopupBusinessChallenge,
        }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
    }
}
```

my Div:

```
<div id="dvbusinesschallengedialouge" style="display: none;">
    <p>
        <span style="color: #E20074; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">
            Idea Challenge :
        </span>
    </p>
    <ol>
        <li type="disc" class="liheader">Local Tools Indentification</li>
        <li type="disc" class="liheader">Opportunity (or Pain Point):</li>

    </ol>
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 10px;">
        <a target="" id="btnlnkButton" href="SubmitIdea.aspx?businessidea=1">
            <img style="width: 180px;" src="../images/submitIdea.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a popup window with a hyperlink in it.  What exactly do you want to happen when you click on the hyperlink?

Comment: I want to navigate to that link, but keep the kendo window visible.

Comment: Have you tried `target="_blank"`?

Comment: yes, the new page is of course displayed, but the kendo window is no longer visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are slightly confused on what the Kendo UI Window widget actually is. It is not a true window. You cannot leave it visible when navigating to another page. It's HTML styled to look like a window. It's an illusion. Once you navigate away, it's not rendered anymore. The page has been replaced. Even if your link target is a blank window, you cannot drag it across to another page. It cannot be dragged outside the boundaries of the page.

Instead, you may want to render your window content in an actual window as opposed to a Kendo widget. In other words, your popup will be it's own standalone HTML page that you open in a blank window.